# How can I allow report viewers to exclude rows from an average?

Tags: powerbi

I create monthly reports of the average productivity of employees. Managers can view the average productivity of the entire organisation, and every employee's productivity seperately.

Some employee's are currently not working (at full capacity). These employees are lowering the average productivity of the organisation. I want to provide a way for my managers to dynamically exclude certain employees from the average.

I used to make these reports in Excel. I am in the process of making the same reports in PowerBI so that the reports are much more dynamic and give more insight.

In Excel, I had made an "exclude" colomn, where managers can put a X in a cell to exclude that row. I calculated the average with:

> =AVERAGEIF( *exclude column* ;""; *productivity column* )

**Ideal solution**

A column with a checkbox for each row. If it's checked, it will be excluded from the average. However, if there exists a feature in PowerBI to filter rows dynamically, that would be great too!

Answer (score 0):

I guess a few items....one solution, add a slicer:

1. Add a column the employee data table to id the exclude status.

   ```
    Exclude = "No"
   ```

this will default all of the employees to No

2. In the report tab create a slicer and add exclude to the field section.  Then the managers can use the slicer to filter the employees they want via selecting "Yes" in the slicer
3. To create a measure to calculate average productivity for include files, you can add another measure:

   ```
    Average Productivity = CALCULATE(
   AVERAGE(YourTable[Productivity]),
   YourTable[Exclude] = "No")
   ```
4. Add a visual and add average productivity measure to display it.

Issue for maintaining it is that exclude record should be updated when the employee status changes.

Working through this, I think what's going to come up next is, the what abouts...e.g. how does this account when my people are in training, on vacation, something else that pulls them away from doing widgets and messing up the production metrics?

I'd suggest:

1. Adding a slicer to add the EmployeeID or EmployeeName so that managers can see the employees and filter them in or out based on their knowledge
2. Create a measure that has some kind of threshold to only calculate employees who have worked a certain number of hours, like:

```
Selected Average Productivity = 
VAR ThresholdHours = 20
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(YourTable[Productivity]),
    YourTable[HoursWorked] >= ThresholdHours
)
```

3. Then Calculate computes the average productivity for employees who have worked at least 20 (or whatever the number is) hours

Then there is no need to maintain the exclude column.

It'll depend a bit on how the company is set up, but my experience has been, when there is a performance metric, there tends to be conditions added to it.  The exclude one would be a better fit if you can limit those conditions (e.g. we only don't count people who are in HR as part time as that'd be easier to maintain)  The threshold if it's murkier with the option to change to a switch statement to evaluate multiple conditions if need be.

Comment: Thanks for you elaborate answer!

I went to give it a try, but I can't seem to get the Slicer to be a toggle between No and Yes. The slicer simply shows "Exclude" with the only option being "No". If i add the Employee ID to the slicer, it just shows a list of employee ID's with each having the "No" value. 

So in short, how can I have the slicer toggle the Exclude column to Yes?